# c++ passing std::function from another class to a constructor

Tags: c++, std, std-function

I am passing a method into a constructor, but when I used a method that another class, it gives me an error.

It is currently working in this form;

```
unsigned int pHash(const std::string& str)
{
    //method
}
int main()
{
//stuff
HashMap* hm2 = new HashMap(pHash);
//stuff
}
```

However, if I reference another header file's method like so;

```
HashMap* hm2 = new HashMap(&HashFcn::primeHash);
```

I get an error at runtime with the follow messages;

```
Error   1   error C2100: illegal indirection    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 273 1   Project
    Error   2   error C2440: 'newline' : cannot convert from 'const std::string *' to 'const HashFcn *' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 273 1   Project
    Error   3   error C2647: '.*' : cannot dereference a 'unsigned int (__thiscall HashFcn::* )(const std::string &)' on a 'const std::string'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 273 1   Project
```

My hashmap constructor looks like this;

```
HashMap::HashMap(HashFunction hashFunction)
    : hfunc(hashFunction)
```

where hfunc is a typdef of a method.

I have a class HashFcn which has the method primeHash

```
unsigned int primeHash(const std::string&);
```

This is my first time doing typdef / method passing -- any clues or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making primeHash static:

```
  static unsigned int primeHash(const std::string&);
```

Comment: works! is it because the &HashFcn::primeHash references the class' method and not an object's? Also, instead of making the method static, is there a way of putting a method of an object through the params of HashMap?

Comment: @RichardLee: I imagine your HashFunction is a regular function and not a method.  A static member function acts like a regular function, but a non-static member function is different, since it requires a value for "this".

Comment: @RichardLee: If you are using C++11, you can use std::function to handle either bound member functions or regular functions.

Comment: Thanks very much Vaughn. I was wondering why it kept asking for "more" parameters. I will study the relation between "this" and std::function loading a bit more.